# Jquery - Linking external .js file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, external

For some reason the external .js file I am linking to isn't working. I am linking to it like so:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have tested jquery using a simple inline script to hide a paragraph of text when it is clicked on so the jquery library is present and working.

The jquery.js file is in the same folder as the index.php file that is calling it.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I have in the external .js file currently just to test it is working(it isn't):

```
$("document").ready(function(){

    $("p").click(function(){
        $("p").css("color", "red");

    });


});
```

Comment: why are you including 2 versions of jQuery?

Comment: the jquery.js file is not the jquery library, just what I have called the .js file.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(document) instead of $("document")?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Problem 1**

It looks like jquery.js contains the code you wrote that *depends* on jQuery.

You need to load jQuery **before** you try to use it.

Swap the order of the `<script>` elements.

---

**Problem 2**

`$("document")` will wait for `<document>` elements to be ready. HTML doesn't have such a thing. Lose the quotes to pass in the `document` object directly.

Better yet, forget about the explicit call to `ready` and just

```
jQuery(function () { /* your function */ });
```