# Is it possible to load external javascript files (from URLs) from the console, in chrome?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, manual

I want to semi-automate some actions.

I want the JQuery library to be loaded in a certain page, to allow me to easier manipulate/query the DOM, to get some data. The page is not under my control, but I don't want to write a crawler for it....I just want to manually crawl the data, from the console.

Can I somehow make my console download and execute the script here ""https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"?

If not, why not?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934234/jquery-linking-external-js-file-not-working

Comment: Check here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7474354/include-jquery-in-the-javascript-console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your console download and execute scripts by appending a `script` tag with the `src` of the script.

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js");
document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Paste this in your console:

```
    var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
  alert("Script loaded and ready");
};
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

From here:[document.createElement("script") synchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)